# WLAN: get info about AP

Tags: wifi, dhcp, wlan

I am troubleshooting WLAN connections from my laptop. I have several possible WLANs to connect to. When connection is established, I am unable to see to which AP I am connected.

In my `/var/log/daemon.log` I only see the DHCP negotiation, but I don't see the AP info.

I am using `Debian` and `dhclient`.

Is there a way to get info about the AP I am currently connected to? Can I make the logging more verbose in `/var/log/daemon.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `iwconfig`, it might be in the wireless-tools package if not already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing `wicd` it is the best tool for wifi management if you have running `X-Desktop environment` .